# nginx adds :8080 to url when no trailing slash is present. How can I configure it to not do that?

Tags: docker, nginx, web, devops, nginx-config

when navigating to www.my-page-com/web/admin, nginx redirects to www.my-page-com:8080/web/admin/.

It's an angular app that I build with docker with this commands:

```
# base image
FROM node:16-alpine as build
ARG version_suffix=0

WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
ENV version=$version_suffix

COPY . /app
RUN npm install -g npm@latest
RUN npm install

# build
RUN ng build --output-path=publish --base-href /web/admin/ --configuration=production

# base image
FROM nginx:1.21
RUN rm -r /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build /app/publish /usr/share/nginx/html/web/admin
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY entrypoint.sh /etc/nginx/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x "/etc/nginx/entrypoint.sh"
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/etc/nginx/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Why is the port in there?

this is my nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    port_in_redirect off;
    absolute_redirect off;
    proxy_redirect off;

    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript          text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_comp_level 9;

    location ^~ /web/admin/index.html {
      # kill cache
      add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
      add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
      if_modified_since off;
      expires off;
      etag off;
    }

    location ^~ /web/admin/assets/i18n/ {
      # kill cache
      add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
      add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
      if_modified_since off;
      expires off;
      etag off;
    }

    location ^~ /web/admin/assets/ {
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
      expires 5m;
    }

    location ^~ /web/admin/components-web/ {
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
      expires 5m;
    }

    location ^~ /web/admin {
      rewrite /web/admin/ permanent;
    }

    location ~ \.(json)$ {
      # kill cache
      add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
      add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
      if_modified_since off;
      expires off;
      etag off;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:ico|gif|jpeg|png|svg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$ {
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
      expires 5m;
    }

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /web/admin/index.html =404;
      # # kill cache
      # add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
      # add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
      # if_modified_since off;
      # expires off;
      # etag off;
    }

  }
}
```

I expect nginx to not add :8080.

I already tried

`port_in_redirect off; absolute_redirect off; proxy_redirect off;`

but it did not change the behavior.

What works (I think) is the rewrite: it adds a / at the end of the url but keeps the :8080. What am I missing?

When I am building and running the docker stuff locally, it seems not to do that.

Comment: The problem solved itself with no additional changes. I am stunned.